# Swift: What do brackets around an if condition change?

Tags: xcode, swift

I try to get to grips with Swift and how to best separate nil and valid objects from optionals.

I have this code:

```
var my AwesomeDict = [:]()
...
... (myAwesomeDict gets populated)
...
let myOptionalObject:objectClass? = myAwesomeDict[key]
if let myUnwrappedObject = myOptionalObject {
    ...
} else {
    println("Sorry, object is nil")
}
```

When I put brackets around the if clause (I feel it improves readability), XCode will flag the line with a compiler error:

> Pattern variable binding cannot appear in an expression

What is different about

```
if (let myUnwrappedObject = myOptionalObject) {
```

from

```
if let myUnwrappedObject = myOptionalObject {
```

? Sadly, the documentation makes no mention of the effect of braces around if conditions. It seems I need to use the bracket-free version, but would like to become more enlightened about the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID435):

The syntax of `if` statement is

```
if [condition] {
    [statements]
}
```

And `[condition]` here is defined as:

> `if-condition` → `expression`­ | `value-binding-pattern­`

---

Here, `let ...` is a ["Value-Binding Pattern"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID422).

> `value-binding-pattern` → var `­pattern` |­  let `­pattern`­

As for `( ... )`, it's not a `value-binding-pattern` because it doesn't start with `let` nor `var`, hence it must be a expression. In the specifications of expressions, the only we can find that starts with `(` and end with `)` is called ["Parenthesized Expression"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID395).

> `parenthesized-expression` → ( `­expression-element-list`<sub>­opt</sub> ­)­

`expression-element-list` is basically a comma delimited list of expressions. And expression does not include `value-binding-pattern`. That's why you cannot put brackets around the `let ...`.

Answer (score 7):

Well here, `if let` is a pattern itself. So if you put a bracket between the if and let, you break the pattern.

If you do that, Swift thinks that you want to check the `let` itself.

So simply said: If you use `if let` don't use brackets, because it breaks the `if let` pattern.

Comment: I found your answer easier to understand but must admit that I learned more from @rintaro's answer. I dithered which one to accept and finally decided for his.